# tkinter.font.Font() does not work

Tags: python, fonts, tkinter

Why does this not work? I have the `Consolas` font on my computer but the below code only uses the default font. It seems the only font which works is the `Courier` font, installed with tkinter.

```py
font_consolas = tkinter.font.Font(root, family="Consolas")
```

Running it with `exists=True` shows the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    font_consolas = tkinter.font.Font(root, family="Consolas", exists=True)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\font.py", line 86, in __init__
    "named font %s does not already exist" % (self.name,))
_tkinter.TclError: named font font1 does not already exist
```

I do have the font installed and it is verified by

```py
'Consolas' in tkinter.font.families() == True
```

Specifying the font in a list works, though

```py
font_consolas = ["Consolas", ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, `Font(...)` will throw an error if the assertion (`exists=True`) is false. The assertion is based on the name of the *new* font, not the name of the font you're basing it on.

It's not throwing the error because the `Consolas` font doesn't exist, it's that it's trying to create a *new* font with a *new name*, and that new font does not exist. Since you don't give it a name, it will pick a unique name, and since by definition a unique name won't previously exist, you get the error. In effect you're saying "create a unique name for my font, and throw an error if this unique name isn't unique"

In other words, it's doing what it's documented to do.

Comment: If I remove the `exists=True`, it doesn't throw an error but the font doesn't work (it's the default).

Comment: @minerz029: you need to create the smallest possible program that exhibits the problem if you want more help. Usually, simply going through that effort will make the problem evident. And if not, edit your question to include the program and maybe we can spot where else you have a problem.